# SELECT the same column multiple times (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, select

**NOTE**: In hindsight, I realize this may seem like a stupid question, but I really did research it quite a bit before posting here. It was just one of those "right-under-your-nose" kind of answers, ugh!

I have tried to combine multiple simple lookup tables into one as I've been told is common practice. I have combined a table containing Statuses and one containing Priority levels as follows:

```
StatusPriority( ID, Name )
Projects( ID, ProjectName, StatusID, PriorityID ) --Master table
```

The values for `ID between 1-10` represent my statuses while the values for `ID between 11-20` represent the priority levels. If I were to split these into two table they would be:

```
Status( ID, StatusName )
Priority( ID, PriorityName )
```

**GOAL**

What I want to do is query for these values into two different columns in the result set with joins to a master table called "Projects." I tried the following query, but it doesn't work:

```
select ProjectName, Name as Status, Name as Priority
    from Projects p left outer join
    StatusPriority st on p.StatusID = st.Name left outer join
    StatusPriority pr on p.PriorityID = pr.Name
```

**SAMPLE RESULTS**

```
    ProjectName         |  Status       |  Priority
    --------------------|---------------|-----------
    Pick Blueberries    |  on hold      |  medium
    Remodel bathroom    |  in progress  |  low
    Plant garden        |  in progress  |  high
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're criteria for the joins looks wrong, as p.StatusID I can't imagine would be equal to st.Name.  secondly you need to use your table aliases on the select list:

```
select ProjectName, st.Name as StatusName, pr.Name as PriorityName
    from Projects p 
    left join StatusPriority st on p.StatusID = st.ID 
    left join StatusPriority pr on p.PriorityID = pr.ID
```

Comment: This is one of those moments in life when you feel like a complete idiot, lol. I actually just realized it right before you answered, but you're exactly right. Thanks :)
...On another note, I think I know the answer, but can referential integrity be enforced when combining tables like this?

Comment: I think it might be possible with an additional CodeCategory column and more complicated constraints, but IMO it's more trouble than its worth.  Even if it is it essentially would require you code the constraint every time you referenced that combined code table to limit keys to those of a specifically hardcoded CodeCategory.

Answer (score 2):

Combining tables like this is a SQL antipattern. Do not do it. You can now only enforce data integrity through triggers instead of with an FK constraint. Depending on how often you need to use it it also can be an area of the database where blocks occur.

It is a very bad practice to  "The values for ID between 1-10 represent my statuses while the values for ID between 11-20 represent the priority levels" What happens when you need the 11th status? If you must combine the tables at least add a column to specify which lookup is which instead of relying on the numbers. But frankly I would never combine lookup tables into one table.

Comment: Wow, seriously thank you for your advice. You're a user I respect very much. I'm sure you have a great reason for this. For my own learning, would you please give me an example of how this can make bad things happen, even if ALL combined tables are extremely static? Thanks again :)

Comment: @Chiramisu When they are combined, the FK constraint won't be able to prevent you from referencing status id 7 with the Projects.PriorityID field.  So you lose the ability for the DB to act as a safety net and prevent bad data/bugs.  If you did add a CodeCategory column as HLGEM suggested, then I **think** you could create more complex constraints that would for example limit PriorityID's to only ID's of the PriorityCodeCategory.  So you are creating more work for yourself.

Comment: Also I find that my code tables often have more than just a ID and text, but other columns to assist client applications.  A simplistic example would be a County table that includes several columns for county codes from different standards such as FIPS as well as abbreviated county names.  Also, separate code tables make it easier to implement new codes which essentially can be a way to implement changes to client applications with no coding or deployment effort.  Usually we don't see the usefulness of this until we are face-to-face with such an opportunity.

Comment: @AaronLS Indeed, I've actually considered the erroneous data issue. After further thought, I think I really gain nothing but headaches by combining the tables, and without any real benefit. I still have the same number of joins, same number of rows; only fewer tables, but without the referential integrity. It seems since I gain no advantage, it would indeed be best to separate them again. I appreciate your great comments Aaron, thanks so much ;)

Comment: It also becomes a hot spot that too many queries are referencing which can end up causing locks.

Answer (score 1):

Are the `StatusID` & `PriorityID` columns within projects represented as the ID of Status Priority? That's what it seems as though you are doing:

```
select ProjectName, st.Name as Status, pr.Name as Priority
    from Projects p 
    left outer join StatusPriority st on p.StatusID = st.ID
    left outer join StatusPriority pr on p.PriorityID = pr.ID
```

Comment: You will get an ambiguous column error with this because it doesn't know if Name is referring to st.Name or pr.Name

Comment: Thanks Aaron, overlooked that. Corrected now.